# Strict Weak Ordering of "i" and "Love"

Tags: c++, string

Assumption:: a < b returns true when a precedes b.

Code

```
std::string a = "i";
std::string b = "Love";
std::cout << "(a < b) = " <<  ((a < b) ? "true" : "false");
```

Output

```
(a < b) = false
```

We know "i" preceedes "Love" so why is the above code return false?

Is my initial assumption wrong?

Help is appreciated thanks.

Comment: Do not tag C for C++ questions.

Comment: _"...We know "i" preceedes "Love" ..."_ you might want to check this assumption - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ascii

Comment: the keyword you want is "case-insensitive comparison"

Comment: There is no requirement in the C++ language that the value that represents the character '`i`' is less than the value that represents the character `'L'`. In fact, it seems to be just the opposite for the character encoding that your compiler is using. The **only** language requirement for character sets is that the values of the characters `'0' .. '9'` must be adjacent and increasing. That lets you do `ch - '0'` to convert a digit character to the value that the character represents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lowercase “l” has a higher character code than uppercase “L” in the character encoding your C++ implementation uses. Most C++ implementations currently use ASCII for the characters A-Z and a-z. In ASCII, the code for “L” is 76, and the code for “i” is 105.

To see the codes your C++ implementation uses for characters, you can convert them to `int` and print them. Here is an example using a character constant:

```
std::cout << static_cast<int>('i') << '\n'; // Will print 105 in implementations that use ASCII.
```

For string literals and strings generally, you can select individual characters using subscripts:

```
std::cout << static_cast<int>("Love"[0]) << '\n'; // Will print 76 in implementations that use ASCII.
```

When you want to compare individual characters ignoring case, you can use `toupper` or `tolower` (declared in `<cctype>`) to convert both characters to the same case for comparison:

```
std::cout << (tolower(a[0]) < tolower(b[0]) ? "true" : "false") << '\n';
```

To do this for strings, you may need to write additional code; I am not aware of a case-insensitive string compare in the standard C++ library.

Answer (score 4):

In ASCII uppercase come earlier than lowercase. You can print its values by `std::cout << (int)'L' << ' ' << (int)'i';`

Comment: But there is a comparision of 2 strings, so there must be operator< working...

Comment: @korzck: The fact that the compiler accepts `a < b` and the program runs means the expression was accepted grammatically and something was executed, but it does not mean the expression **works** to produce the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Other users have already pointed out that in most common character encodings (i.e.: ASCII and Unicode), lower-case letter `i` does *not* precede upper-case letter `L`. Read more about [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) and [the difference between lower- and upper-case letters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_case).

I'd like to add that if you want to perform a comparison without caring about letter case (so that `i` precedes `L` like you want), you can make use of specific functions like POSIX-compliant [`strcasecmp()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcasecmp). [See also other methods to compare strings ignoring the case](https://www.delftstack.com/howto/cpp/compare-strings-ignore-case-cpp).